Can monorail motor (2684c01a/b) be powered at 12V?
Does anyone know if the monorail motor (part 2684c01a/b) can be powered by a 12V supply?
There is this well-known article titled "LEGO® 9V Technic Motors compared characteristics" which provides information for many (if not all) of the other motors from Lego - and this supports what I have found in tests with the Power Functions M, L and XL motors, being that 12V is handled fine. However, it does not include results for the monorail motor.
The monorail motor is a much rarer and more expensive part than other Lego motors, thereby one I would really hate to damage, so I wondered if anyone had any knowledge on the subject before I start potentially damaging tests.

I apologize if this is an obvious answer, or better suited to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, but:
You can use an inexpensive 12V→9V step-down DC/DC transformer. There's plenty of different options, but I picked a couple of available transformers in order to let you have a rough idea of their size:


The connection is straightforward - terminals marked "in" or "12V" go to the 12V power supply, and terminals marked "out" or "9V" go to the 9V motor.
Let me also quote from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/448650/ :

The speed of a brushed DC motor is roughly proportional to the voltage applied, given the same countertorque.
There's a reason that motor is designed for 6V only. DC brushed motors are very forgiving, even the commutator and the bearing should stand 1.5 times the design speed for a long time.
But the gears don't.
It's most likely a plastic gearbox. Running it at overspeed will destroy the innermost gear very quickly. Don't do it.

Which means: do not connect your 9V monorail motor directly to a 12V power source. It will most probably run fine, but the gears made out of 30-years-old plastic will disintegrate.
See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104749 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112000/ - there's no further considerations to attaching a DC motor to a step-down buck transformer.

The information in your links is very helpful.  Having repaired a few Lego motors I know they do contain a plastic gearbox.  If it is the speed as opposed to the voltage that causes any damage then I would think that a 12V supply on a 75% PWM duty cycle brings us back to the operating tolerance of the gearbox (unless the on/off nature of PWM causes any additional stress?).  The first article from which you quote mentions a 150% tolerance for the motor itself.  Here 12V/9V = 133% so we are within that.

I read somewhere that Lego motors are in fact rated 12V but I can't find the article.  If anyone knows of it, I think it would be a valuable addition to this thread.

Finally, to shed light on the reason for considering 12V, it is simply that MN21 batteries (including holder) fit within a 2-stud space, so are particulary appealing where space is at a premium.  Whether they can supply sufficient current to operate the motor is yet to be established.

I guess your follow-up question about PWM is better suited to electronics.stackexchange.
